# Is the accuracy of nextProbablePrime() related to size of input value?

Tags: java, hashtable, primes, biginteger

I'm using BigInteger's [nextProbablePrime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#nextProbablePrime()) in a homework assignment to calculate the next prime number I can use to resize a hash table that uses quadratic probing.

The table stores data items read in from a file. The sample file I've been given contains only 100 items, but I can't assume that this is the maximum data set my program will be tested on.

I'm wondering if there is any relationship between the size of the value that I pass to nextProbablePrime and the likelihood that it will correctly return a prime number? In other words, is there a number below which nextProbablePrime is guaranteed to be accurate? Is it reasonable for me to rely on it?

Comment: Unless this is a requirement, I would kept things simpler.  You could look at Hashtable which uses a simple progression, or HashMap which uses powers of two. I find that reducing the loading factor can make up for a non-ideal, but reasonable, hash function.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Sadly, I am restricted to writing my own class and forbidden from using HashMaps etc. I think your point about the load factor is a good one, so I have reduced it to 0.5, thanks!

Comment: You can run a performance test to find the optimal load factor for you dataset. While you cannot use Hashtable or HashMap you can read all its code, might give you some ideas. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since "the probability that the number returned by this method is composite does not exceed `2^-100`" I think it is reasonable for you to assume to rely on it returning a prime number.

Answer (score 0):

nextProbablePrime() is actually used for cryptographic operations which require to find (really) huge numbers that are "probably prime". The nextProbablePrime() method returns a number that is prime with a probability of 2^-100.

I don't think such a method is useful for your needs. For reasonable numbers (like the size of a hashtable), you can simply check if a number is prime using a simple home-made implementation, especially if high performance is required.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine for your purpose.

Better would be to use a pre-computed list of hash table sizes. You probably only need a half-dozen or so; choose based on the expected size of your hash table, and grow if the load factor gets too big.

The general lesson is to take all possible methods to reduce the complexity of your code. You're writing a hash table. You don't need to worry about prime numbers.